# Encrypting files with Java 7 at local using AWS KMS Data Keys

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, encryption

I am trying to encrypt/decrypt local files with AWS KMS DataKey but I don't know what to use to do it.

I have already generated the DataKey from AWS KMS *(receiving the Plaintext Key and the Encrypted Key)*. Now it's supposed I have to use the Plaintext key to encrypt the file, store the Encrypted key with the Final Encrypted file and delete the Plaintext key.

How do I encrypt a file in Java 7 using that Plaintext Key? I mean, there are several ways to do it but which is the most effective and secure with AES_256 cipher I request to AWS KMS to get the keys?

```
//AWS KMS requesting data key
GenerateDataKeyRequest dataKeyRequest = new GenerateDataKeyRequest()
dataKeyRequest.setKeyId(keyId)
dataKeyRequest.setKeySpec("AES_256")
    
GenerateDataKeyResult dataKeyResult = awskmsClient.generateDataKey(dataKeyRequest)
ByteBuffer plaintextKey = dataKeyResult.getPlaintext()
ByteBuffer encryptedKey = dataKeyResult.getCiphertextBlob()
```

I cannot use AWS Encryption to do that (even it would be easier) because o Java 7 version

Comment: Why not upgrade to Java 8 then you have access to the AWS SDK V2 KMS Service

Comment: The AWS Encryption SDK (_unrelated to the KMS SDK, v1 or v2_) uses [Bouncy Castle](https://www.bouncycastle.org/java.html) to do the actual work. There are versions of BC available for JVMs going back to (I think) 1.3.